# Readonly Store that extends BehaviorSubject

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a problem with nested objects that are stored in `BehaviorSubject`s that allow for mutation inside an application I'm working on (RxJs & TypeScript with Angular).

I want to solve this by making a new type `Store` that extends `BehaviorSubject` but makes sure whatever data stored is immutable.

I've ended up with more or less this class:

```
export class Store<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {
  constructor(initialData: T) {
    super(deepFreeze(initialData));
  }

  next(newData: T): void {
    super.next(deepFreeze(newData));
  }

  getValue(): Readonly<T> {
    return super.getValue() as Readonly<T>;
  }
}
```

Which gives me a runtime error when I try to mutate objects like this:

```
someStore$ = new Store({ firstLevel: { secondLevel: [] }});

someStore$.subscribe(val => val.firstLevel.secondLevel = ["que?"]);
```

However, I'd also like TypeScript to let developers know that the operation is invalid, letting the linter instruct the developer that he/she is doing something illegal.

How do I go about doing this correctly? Do I somehow have to override the `subscribe`-function inside Store? I was hoping throuwing `Readonly` around the return type of `getValue()` would do the trick, but neither the example above or the following example give me a linting error:

`someStore$.getValue().firstLevel.secondLevel = ["si!"]`

How would I go about making sure immutability of these objects is notified using Typescript and not just errors in runtime?

For reference, `deepFreeze` is implemented as the following:

```
export function deepFreeze<T>(object: T): Readonly<T> {
  const propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);
  for (const name of propNames) {
    const value = object[name];
    object[name] =
      value && typeof value === "object" ? deepFreeze(value) : value;
  }

  return Object.freeze(object);
}
```

(Based on the MDN documentation of Object.freeze)